# Create Custom controllers and Views in Radiant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radiant

I have asked this question in Radiant CMS google group, but no one answered my question.

I have been searching to see if Radiant is able to integrate into
existing projects. And I saw this in the mail archive
http://www.mail-archive.com/radiant@radiantcms.org/msg04311.html It
seems that we can only package our existing projects as an extension
and put it in the Radiant project, but not the other way round.
However, I don’t understand that why we can’t do it.

In radiant project, there is no app folder, where it should contain
controllers, helpers and views.  So why can’t we create the directory
in this project. E.g. app/customs_controller.rb, and create an action
inside, and create the views. Now we just modify the routes.rb in
config/routes.rb to be able to map to this controller. Then we are
able to do any dynamic pages that we wanted. Isn’t it?

One of the concerns is that if we do this the future upgrade of
Radiant maybe difficult?

Thank you very much.
Shanison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. I have found my own answers, the answer is no. I have written a details article on this shanison.com/2011/03/29/radiant-cms-vs-refinery-cms